# Solana deploy "account data too small for instruction"

Tags: solana

When i try to deploy a program with anchor (devnet or mainnet, same error), i get the following error : Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction.

I have no clue where this comes from.

The so file is around 331Ko, and apparently, the error shows up when i try to use "mpl-token-metadata" to get metadata of NFT

Any one has an idea how to correct that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you deploy a program on Solana, the amount of space allocated for that program is 2x the original program size.

This is to ensure there is a good amount of space if you upgrade the program, up to 2x the original program size.

The program that you are deploying is exceeding this limit. You will have to get a new programId and deploy again.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I'm using anchor, how can i get a new programId ? Do i have a create a new one from 0 and copy paste everything ?

Comment: For Anchor, you will need to delete the keypair in the `target/deploy` directory and redeploy from scratch

Comment: @JacobCreech Is there a way to increase program size limit? i've heard something about `reallocate` but idk if it can be used on program account. Redeploying to a new address could bring more problem if a the contract have users and data on PDAs already.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the `target` folder

Run `anchor build`, this will add a new keypair to `target/deploy`

run `anchor keys list`, this will give you the new program id

copy the id to the top of your `lib.rs`

run `anchor build` again

and `anchor deploy`

Comment: Although the accepted answer provides insight on the issue, these instructions provide the "how to" to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to redeploy your program.

Using Solana CLI (>1.18) you can do:

```bash
$ solana program extend <PROGRAM_ID> <MORE_BYTES>
```

To allocate more bytes, then try again.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: `$ solana program extend prog111111111111111111111111111111111111111 20000 -u d -k ./authority_keypair.json`

Where -u is the rpc url or moniker (d for devnet in this example)
-k the path to the program upgrade authority keypair (signer)
20000 is 20 kb more space, adjust properly. And prog111111111111111111111111111111111111111 should be your deployed program id.